# How to save a value of a String variable and use it later when i wish even every time i run the code?

Tags: java

I have a requirement that i have some String values and i have to save the values somewhere say in a list.And the values once i inserted into the list should remain there.So that if i want to use that values later i should not put  those values in the list again.i am giving a simple piece of code to illustrate my problem...

```
public class Chkrecords {

public static void main(String a[]){

    List<String> inti=new ArrayList<>();



    String arr[]={"a","b","c","d"};

//      for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
//          
//          inti.add(String.valueOf(arr[i]));
//      }
     System.out.println(inti);

}
}
```

this is the piece of code i am trying to implement ... the for loop is going to insert the values for the first time.And from then i don't want to use that loop again,but i want the values be in the list..Can anyone help me....

Comment: The values *will* be in the list after that loop (you also don't need `String.valueOf()`, just use `arr[i]`.) I'm not sure what your issue is?

Comment: Once you have inserted the value, they _are_ going to stay in the list, unless you delete them yourself.

Comment: do you mean that you want the values to be there every time you run the program?

Comment: Perhaps one of these tutorials will help: [Variables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html), [Member Variables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html), [Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/index.html).

Comment: @SamIam yes i mean that.. every time i run the program values will be there..is that so easy friend ??

Answer (score 1):

> How to save a value of a String variable and use it later when i wish??

You can create the variable as instance variable like:

```
public class Chkrecords {

    private String var = "Something";

    public static void main(String a[]){
        // you can access the var directly from any method in this class.
        System.out.println(var);
    }

    public String getVar() {// to be able to access var variable from outside the class
        return var;
    }
}
```

And if you want to use that var each time you Run your program, you can just [serialize](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=57) that object.

Answer (score 0):

`every time i run the program values will be there`

You're going to have to write the values to a file, and then you're going to have to read them back from the file every time you run the program.

You can't just put them in a variable and expect that to persist across instances of the program.  The variables won't just sit in memory forever.

Comment: i am not talking about persistent storage,i want to use something in the memory

Comment: @lucifer well in that case, the answer would be "you can't"